# Как автоматически обрезать картинки в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, cms, resize, изображения, crop

Здравствуйте! Наткнулся на такую вот проблему:
я загружаю картинку к примеру (1000х1000) в менеджере вордпресс он режет мне миниатюру так как нужно, то есть обрезает её на 400х276, а вот размер "мидл" и "лардж" он берет от пропорций оригинала, а мне нужно чтобы он брал от пропорций миниатюры.
То есть у меня:
"мини" = 400х276
"мидл" = 638х440
"лардж" = 826х570
менеджер режет картинку так: мидл = 440х440, лардж = 570х570
а мне нужно:
"мидл" = 638х440
"лардж" = 826х570

Может есть какие-то плагины, посоветуйте, или еще какой-то выход из ситуации, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить свои размеры для mini, middle и large на админ-странице /wp-admin/options-media.php

Теперь вновь добавляемые изображения будут резаться по этим размерам.

Для того, чтобы переделать миниатюры ранее загруженных изображений, удобно воспользоваться весьма известным плагином [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). Он пересоздаст все ранее созданные миниатюры.